# Exception handling in Spring - Controller or Service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception, error-handling

I have simple REST endpoint:

```
    @PatchMapping(value = "/{projectId}/change-owner/{volunteerId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> changeProjectOwner(@PathVariable Long projectId,
                                                         @PathVariable Long volunteerId
    ) {

        Project foundProject = projectService.findProject(projectId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(PROJECT_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE));
        Volunteer foundVolunteer = volunteerService.findVolunteer(volunteerId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(VOLUNTEER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE));

        ProjectDTO projectDTO = projectService.changeOwner(foundVolunteer, foundProject).orElseThrow(() -> new AccessDeniedException(PERMISSION_DENIED_MESSAGE));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(projectDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and service corresponding to it:

```
    public Optional<ProjectDTO> changeOwner(Volunteer user, Project project) {

        if (this.isVolunteerProjectOwner(volunteerService.getLoggedVolunteer(), project) || authenticationService.checkIfAdmin(volunteerService.getLoggedVolunteer())) {

            project.setOwnerVolunteer(user);

            projectRepository.save(project);

            return Optional.of(projectMapper.mapProjectToDTO(project));
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

I feel that something is wrong with this approach. I have many endpoints like this, but I cannot really design error handling for more specific scenarios since service is able to return `Optional.empty()` in case of failure. I am wondering whether I should throw exceptions within service layer. I am using `@RestControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` annotations. If I decided to throw exceptions within services, that would mean that I have to annotate controller with `throws` keyword which is considered a bad practice (as far as I know). Generally I heard that throwing exceptions in services is not a good practice. But if I put all error checks within controller, I will break SRP principle, and code would be tightly organised that is why I don't want to put all `if` within controllers since all code would appear messy. I am confused whether I should move all logic to controllers and handle specific scenarios or put `throws (some exception)` on controller and make `@RestControllerAdvice` take care of it.

Comment: Throw exceptions in any site not a bad practice by itself, you need consider if the exception you want throw coming from the "correct" layer. For example if you have a repository and you have a exception from the repository you should throw the exception from there and not from the service. And the solution you want came just replacing the empty optional return, and throw a specific exception you previously configured for trigger the controller advice

Comment: So I can add ```throws``` keyword to controller and service methods and it won't be considered bad practice? Custom exceptions require to be handled in some way, either by ```try/catch``` or by annotating methods by ```throws```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my personal opinion, and there's no wrong answer here. Personally, I say throw your exceptions in the Service layer. I've found that in general it's best for your controller layer to be a simple pass through. The reason for this is that controllers are meant to define a request coming in through HTTP but your services should be usable and accessible through any call pattern. For instance lets say you want to add a GraphQL or an SQS call pattern. Your service layer should behave exactly the same in all circumstances, and should throw the same exceptions. Now you have an agnostic service layer that handles all your logic, and the caller is irrelevant.

Comment: Just one question - custom exceptions display an error indicating that we have some unhandled exception so we either need to add ```throws``` keyword or make ```try/catch``` statement. Can I add ```throws``` on controller and service methods without any worry?

Comment: The reason for this is based on the class that you extend from. There are two types of exceptions in Java: "Checked" exceptions and "Unchecked" exceptions. If you don't want your custom exception to be a "Checked" exception then have it extend from `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception`. However as you said, you can always have your controller  methods mark as `throws` for your custom exceptions if you want them to be checked exception